# How to update row values with values from SELECT into another DB in a trigger

Tags: trigger, update, mariadb, insert

I have been working in a trigger for `INSERT|UPDATE` values for a given record based on same `PK`. What trigger basically should do it is, foreach `row` when some `INSERT` happens on `veeva_new.account`:

- Check if PK already exists, if exists then get the values from `veeva_new.account` and `UPDATE` columns on `pdone.targets`
- If PK doesn't exists then `INSERT` the new row (copy row from `veeva_new.account` to `pdone.targets`)

This is what I have so far:

```
#Account ON INSERT AFTER => Add a new record to the targets table or UPDATE its values if record already exists (checking by PK)
USE `veeva_new`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veeva_new.account_ai$$
USE `veeva_new`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `veeva_new`.`account_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `account` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vCount INT(6) DEFAULT 0;

    SET vCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.id);
    IF (vCount>0) THEN
        SET @TargetLastMod=(SELECT targets.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.id LIMIT 0,1); 

        IF (NEW.lastmodifieddate > @TargetLastMod) THEN
            # [Will execute a query for get values from veeva]
            SELECT 
                account.id AS veeva_account_id,
                account.lastmodifieddate AS veeva_timestamp,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(`first`,' ',`last`)) as display_name,
                'https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/no_avatar.png' AS avatar_url,
                account.title__c AS `title`,
                account.firstname AS pdone.LCAPITAL(`first`),
                account.lastname AS pdone.LCAPITAL(`last`),
                account.suffix_vod__c AS `suffix`,
                address_vod__c.name AS `address1`,
                address_vod__c.address_line_2_vod__c AS `address2`,
                address_vod__c.city_vod__c AS `city`,
                address_vod__c.state_vod__c AS `state`,
                address_vod__c.zip_vod__c AS `zip`,
                address_vod__c.phone_vod__c AS `phone`,
                address_vod__c.fax_vod__c AS `fax`,
                -- `state_licensed_id`
                'VEEVA' AS `target_type`,
                account.npi_vod__c AS `npi`,
                FALSE AS `inactive`,
                NOW() AS `lastSyncAt`,
                NOW() AS `createdAt`,
                NOW() AS `updatedAt`
                -- address_vod__c.primary_vod__c,
                -- address_vod__c.license_vod__c,
                -- address_vod__c.lastmodifieddate AS addresslastmodifieddate
            FROM
                account
                    JOIN
                address_vod__c ON address_vod__c.account_vod__c = account.id
            WHERE
                account.id = NEW.id
                    AND external_id_vod__c IS NOT NULL
                    AND address_vod__c.primary_vod__c = 1
                            AND account.recordtypeid COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (SELECT id FROM veeva_new.recordtype WHERE name = 'Professional_vod');

            # [Will update all values for targets]
            UPDATE pdone.targets 
            SET
            `veeva_account_id` =,
            `veeva_timestamp` =,
            `display_name` =,
            `avatar_url` =,
            `title` =,
            `first` =,
            `last` =,
            `suffix` =,
            `address1` =,
            `address2` =,
            `city` =,
            `state` =,
            `zip` =,
            `phone` =,
            `fax` =,
            `target_type` =,
            `npi` =,
            `inactive` =,
            `lastSyncAt` = NOW(),
            `updatedAt` = NOW()
            WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.id; 
        END IF;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO pdone.targets
        (`veeva_account_id`,`veeva_timestamp`,`display_name`,`avatar_url`,`title`,`first`,`last`,`suffix`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`phone`,`fax`,`target_type`,`npi`,`inactive`,`lastSyncAt`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`)
        SELECT 
            account.id AS veeva_account_id,
            account.lastmodifieddate AS veeva_timestamp,
            pdone.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(`first`,' ',`last`)) as display_name,
            'https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/no_avatar.png' AS avatar_url,
            account.title__c AS `title`,
            account.firstname AS pdone.LCAPITAL(`first`),
            account.lastname AS pdone.LCAPITAL(`last`),
            account.suffix_vod__c AS `suffix`,
            address_vod__c.name AS `address1`,
            address_vod__c.address_line_2_vod__c AS `address2`,
            address_vod__c.city_vod__c AS `city`,
            address_vod__c.state_vod__c AS `state`,
            address_vod__c.zip_vod__c AS `zip`,
            address_vod__c.phone_vod__c AS `phone`,
            address_vod__c.fax_vod__c AS `fax`,
            -- `state_licensed_id`
            'VEEVA' AS `target_type`,
            account.npi_vod__c AS `npi`,
            FALSE AS `inactive`,
            NOW() AS `lastSyncAt`,
            NOW() AS `createdAt`,
            NOW() AS `updatedAt`
            -- address_vod__c.primary_vod__c,
            -- address_vod__c.license_vod__c,
            -- address_vod__c.lastmodifieddate AS addresslastmodifieddate
        FROM
            account
                JOIN
            address_vod__c ON address_vod__c.account_vod__c = account.id
        WHERE
            account.id = NEW.id
                AND external_id_vod__c IS NOT NULL
                AND address_vod__c.primary_vod__c = 1
                        AND account.recordtypeid COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (SELECT id FROM veeva_new.recordtype WHERE name = 'Professional_vod');
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger won't work since it has a lot of issues and I am trying to fix them so, between lines `# [Will execute a query for get values from veeva]` and `# [Will update all values for targets]` I should perform a query to `veeva_new.account` and get current row based on `PK` because that `PK` already exists and then I should pass values on that `SELECT` to the `UPDATE` statement just before `# [Will update all values for targets]` comment, how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your `TRIGGER` and I used `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to `UPDATE` all the fields when your `NEW.lastmodifieddate` be greater than `targets.lastSyncAt`.

**Some errors**:

- You've used a `function` on a field label in `pdone.LCAPITAL(first)`, that can't be possible.
- You've used the same `function` now trying to `CONCAT` 2 field labels, instead table fields name `pdone.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(first,' ',last))`.

Now, try this update of the `TRIGGER`:

```
USE `veeva_new`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veeva_new.account_ai$$
USE `veeva_new`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veeva_new`.`account_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `account` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vCount INT(6) DEFAULT 0;
    SET vCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.id);
    IF (vCount>0) THEN
        SET @TargetLastMod=(SELECT targets.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.targets WHERE targets.veeva_account_id=NEW.id LIMIT 0,1); 
        # [ IF EXISTS IN pdone.targets, UPDATE only if NEW.lastmodifieddate IS GREATER than @TargetLastMod ]
        IF (NEW.lastmodifieddate > @TargetLastMod) THEN
            INSERT INTO pdone.targets
            (`veeva_account_id`,`veeva_timestamp`,`display_name`,`avatar_url`,`title`,`first`,`last`,`suffix`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`phone`,`fax`,`target_type`,`npi`,`inactive`,`lastSyncAt`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`)
            SELECT 
                account.id AS veeva_account_id,
                account.lastmodifieddate AS veeva_timestamp,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(account.firstname,' ',account.lastname)) as display_name,
                'https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/no_avatar.png' AS avatar_url,
                account.title__c AS `title`,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(account.firstname) AS `first`,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(account.lastname) AS `last`,
                account.suffix_vod__c AS `suffix`,
                address_vod__c.name AS `address1`,
                address_vod__c.address_line_2_vod__c AS `address2`,
                address_vod__c.city_vod__c AS `city`,
                address_vod__c.state_vod__c AS `state`,
                address_vod__c.zip_vod__c AS `zip`,
                address_vod__c.phone_vod__c AS `phone`,
                address_vod__c.fax_vod__c AS `fax`,
                -- `state_licensed_id`
                'VEEVA' AS `target_type`,
                account.npi_vod__c AS `npi`,
                FALSE AS `inactive`,
                NOW() AS `lastSyncAt`,
                NOW() AS `createdAt`,
                NOW() AS `updatedAt`
                -- address_vod__c.primary_vod__c,
                -- address_vod__c.license_vod__c,
                -- address_vod__c.lastmodifieddate AS addresslastmodifieddate
            FROM
                account
                    JOIN
                address_vod__c ON address_vod__c.account_vod__c = account.id
            WHERE
                account.id = NEW.id
                    AND external_id_vod__c IS NOT NULL
                    AND address_vod__c.primary_vod__c = 1
                            AND account.recordtypeid COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (SELECT id FROM veeva_new.recordtype WHERE name = 'Professional_vod')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            # `veeva_account_id` =, THIS IS TE PK, COULDNT BE UPDATE
            `veeva_timestamp` =NEW.lastmodifieddate,
            `display_name` = pdone.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(account.firstname,' ',account.lastname)),
            `avatar_url` = 'https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/no_avatar.png',
            `title` =account.title__c,
            `first` =pdone.LCAPITAL(account.firstname),
            `last` =pdone.LCAPITAL(account.lastname),
            `suffix` =account.suffix_vod__c,
            `address1` =address_vod__c.name,
            `address2` =address_vod__c.address_line_2_vod__c,
            `city` =address_vod__c.city_vod__c,
            `state` =address_vod__c.state_vod__c,
            `zip` =address_vod__c.zip_vod__c,
            `phone` =address_vod__c.phone_vod__c,
            `fax` =address_vod__c.fax_vod__c,
            `target_type` ='VEEVA',
            `npi` =account.npi_vod__c,
            `inactive` =FALSE,
            `lastSyncAt` = NOW(),
            `updatedAt` = NOW();
        END IF;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO pdone.targets
            (`veeva_account_id`,`veeva_timestamp`,`display_name`,`avatar_url`,`title`,`first`,`last`,`suffix`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`phone`,`fax`,`target_type`,`npi`,`inactive`,`lastSyncAt`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`)
            SELECT 
                account.id AS veeva_account_id,
                account.lastmodifieddate AS veeva_timestamp,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(account.firstname,' ',account.lastname)) as display_name,
                'https://pdone.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/no_avatar.png' AS avatar_url,
                account.title__c AS `title`,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(account.firstname) AS `first`,
                pdone.LCAPITAL(account.lastname) AS `last`,
                account.suffix_vod__c AS `suffix`,
                address_vod__c.name AS `address1`,
                address_vod__c.address_line_2_vod__c AS `address2`,
                address_vod__c.city_vod__c AS `city`,
                address_vod__c.state_vod__c AS `state`,
                address_vod__c.zip_vod__c AS `zip`,
                address_vod__c.phone_vod__c AS `phone`,
                address_vod__c.fax_vod__c AS `fax`,
                -- `state_licensed_id`
                'VEEVA' AS `target_type`,
                account.npi_vod__c AS `npi`,
                FALSE AS `inactive`,
                NOW() AS `lastSyncAt`,
                NOW() AS `createdAt`,
                NOW() AS `updatedAt`
                -- address_vod__c.primary_vod__c,
                -- address_vod__c.license_vod__c,
                -- address_vod__c.lastmodifieddate AS addresslastmodifieddate
            FROM
                account
                    JOIN
                address_vod__c ON address_vod__c.account_vod__c = account.id
            WHERE
                account.id = NEW.id
                    AND external_id_vod__c IS NOT NULL
                    AND address_vod__c.primary_vod__c = 1
                            AND account.recordtypeid COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN (SELECT id FROM veeva_new.recordtype WHERE name = 'Professional_vod');
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should works when trigger is `ON AFTER INSERT` but what about `ON AFTER UPDATE`? How I should deal with that trigger?